# Problems in Link tag

Tags: html, css

hii all i am currently learning external css so i used link tag which helps me out with external css. So basically guys the format of link tag which it shows to me in atom is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/master.css">
```

so the first slash in href tells about root which i don't know in detail as have not yet studied js. So i have removed it. to get the external css  correctly i have done all the correct steps regarding it but the problem arises here....

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

( i applied this due to that i am not getting desired out put )..

So done some research and i came to point that by appling this layout of linktag i am getting desired out put

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\KUSH\Desktop\UDEMY WEEB DEVELOPMENT 2022\css\styles.css">
```

this is the path of my external css folder.

but my prof is using this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

and she is getting desired outputs

so pls help me out with that.....

Comment: is your html file inside a folder? like("root/html/home.html") and css looks like("root/css/style.css")? If so try  ../css/styles.css

Comment: That tells me you're not using a web server to serve your HTML, but directly opening a file in the browser. That is not a good idea at all because there's all kinds of restrictions when directly opening a local file. You need a small web server, try the live server extension https://atom.io/packages/atom-live-server.

Comment: And trust me, you don't want to become a "weeb" developer... :)

Comment: @KUSH please show us your folder and file structure (i.e. where do you put the files). The link you are using is called **absolute path** while your professor is using **relative path**. In web development world, we usually use **relative path** only, therefore you won't see the path starting with a drive `C:` or `file://`. If you use these paths, you're probably wrong.

Comment: @Raptor How can we use relative path

Comment: @KUSHRAJ please post your folder & file structure, so that we can help you. Without knowing your folder structure, I don't know how I can advise further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">`

the ./ means that the path start from the current folder where your Html file is located

Comment: Wrong. `./css/style.css` equals to `css/style.css`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your HTML file and CSS file in same folder which make your work easier[here is the example if you I am not understandable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvp4J.png)

Comment: NEVER do this! This is so unprofessional. You should put CSS in `css` or `style` folder.

Comment: Thats what i tries to say a html separate `html` file and `css`  file

Comment: No, you should place the CSS file in a separate **folder**.

Comment: @Raptor ok my friend just started using stack overflow ..... Thanks for the tip man ✌

Comment: @Rohith_29 ok my friend i didn't knew how to write questions pls guide me with that it would be really a gr8 learning

Comment: @Raptor Sorry buddy my bad I been creating only single pages that's why I said it my bad **sorry BRO**